# How to check the blocking state of AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent in C#?

Tags: c#, synchronization, thread-safety, block

Is it possible to check the blocking state for C# System.Threading.AutoResetEvent or 
System.Threading.ManualResetEvent before calling WaitOne() ?

Comment: Use reflection. What's your actual problem?

Comment: I am developing an UDP client that talks with the special hardware. I had to implement a blocking code to synchronize the communication. The things must run fast so I can't place a breakpoints before WaitOne(). I have 4 AutoResetEvents. When the communication blocks I wanted to know in witch one. I know that writting to console will show where but writting takes time and in such critical envirnoment I can't waste time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An EventWaitHandle doesn't have a "blocking state".  It is set or reset, nothing else.  And no, you cannot check that any other way than by calling WaitOne().

You can pass a 0 for the time-out argument to avoid blocking.  That's often a very bad idea because it says nothing about the state of the event after the WaitOne() call returns.  It might have changed a nanosecond after that.  This causes a very nasty kind of bug called "threading race".  A Heisenbug.

Comment: I know that EventWaithandle doesn't have a blocking state but blocks the current thread execution if it is not signalled. I have 4 EventWaitHandles in the same while loop working in a thread. Some of them must block the thread conditionally. I wanted to know from some other event which of these 4 handles are blocked. I see that I must add some bool variables linked to the handles to get these informations.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public virtual bool WaitOne(
    TimeSpan timeout
)
```

with timeout 0. According to MSDN it will return the state of the WaitHandle immediately.

Comment: A remark to this. I would expect that WaitOne(0) on an AutoResetEvent potentially resets it. You would have to use Set after WaitOne if it was signaled. But I have to agree with Hans about race conditions. This can cause nasty bugs if you have multiple threads which called WaitOne too. No problem with ManualResetEvent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, really just building a demo app. (Newbie to EventWaitHandle.)

This is how I solved the problem (in VB.NET):

```
Module Module1

Dim ewh As Threading.EventWaitHandle

Sub Main()
  ewh = New Threading.EventWaitHandle(False, Threading.EventResetMode.ManualReset)
  ' Do other work.
End Sub

Sub checkBlockStatus()

  ewh.WaitOne()

End Sub

Function isEwhBlocked() As Boolean

  Dim testEwhBlock As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf checkBlockStatus)
  testEwhBlock.Start()
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
  If testEwhBlock.ThreadState <> Threading.ThreadState.Stopped Then
     ' It's OK to use abort here because I don't care what happens to the thread.
     testEwhBlock.Abort()
     Return True
  Else
     Return False
  End If
  testEwhBlock = Nothing

End Function
End Module
```

At any point that you need to check the blocking status of that instance, just do this:

```
if (isEwhBlocked()) Then
  ' This means the block is on.
else
  ' No block.
End If
```

So, no, you can't REALLY figure out what is blocked before calling WaitOne(), but you can run it in an ASync way that prevents it from seizing your main thread. You could probably reduce the sleep value quite a bit as well, if that is too long to wait.

Obviously, if you need to check on multiple blocks, the function gets a tad bit more complex (or you have to create more of them), but this demonstrates the basic principle. I also tested this as an AutoReset, and it doesn't work quite as well. Because the handler is in autoreset, once I call the method to check the block, it resets and blocks my other thread. So if you can run in ManualReset, this could work for you.